# Renaming columns that exist in a data frame while ignoring those that dont

Tags: python, pandas

Some back story to paint a picture. Clients send me excel sheets with a note of what the column headers are linked to so I can map them using python. E.g column A= Claim. The problem lies where I constantly have to remove certain sections of the code that are not applicable. For example, in the instance below the df is only composed of claim, and frog. Whereas my code has an extra goat field. Instead of simply deleting the field, I tried creating a loop, but i'm not sure how to ignore the fact that if I leave df.columns[(ci("")-1)] not populated I want it to skip over the error, and go onto the next interation.

Any thoughts?

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string as ci
df={'Claim':[1,2,3,4,5],'Frog':[2,3,4,5,7]}
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df=df.rename(columns={ df.columns[(ci("A")-1)]:"Claim Number",df.columns[(ci("b")-1)]: "Toad",df.columns[(ci("")-1)]: "Goat"})
```

Comment: Can you explain how the column mapping is read from the excel sheet? Do you know upfront how many column names are mapped?

Comment: The column mapping is on another excel sheet that simply has a list of the column index e.g A,B,C,D,E and what they are mapped too e.g claim, frog, goat, chicken, goose. I know the max number of columns that need to be mapped, 36. But this varries on the client. Some times they are missing columns/ data.

Comment: have you tried something like `try: <your loop code> except ValueError: pass`?

Comment: Also, currently the new name is hardcoded (e.g. `[(ci("A")-1)]:"Claim Number"`. I assume that this information is extracted from the excel sheet, right?

Comment: Correct Jan. Cameron I have not tried that, but I will give it a shot now.